# jQuery's getJSON not maintaining original order

Tags: jquery, json

Having the following file (customers.json):

```
{"3":"Andy", "1":"Bruce", "4":"Charlie", "2":"David"}
```

Using this code:

```
jQuery.getJSON("/Customers.json", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This will output the following:

```
{"1":"Bruce", "2":"David", "3":"Andy", "4":"Charlie"}
```

My Json is purposefully in alphabetical order by the name, but this this code seems to put in numerical order. Is this a feature? And how do I stop this from happening?

Whether it makes a difference, I am using Firefox 39.0

**EDIT:**

The real question here is, is there anyway to do this, keeping ALL the data, and maintaining the order in which is received?

Comment: As per the spec the order of keys can be random..... so you can't depend upon it... if the order is important use an array

Comment: what "spec"? you need to specify what spec you're talking about.

Comment: Every answer to this question just got downvoted. Are you downvoting all the answers that don't solve your Edit or is someone else doing that?

Comment: @Ghazgkull I dunno, I think mine answered the edit. Just some serial downvoter, my guess.

Comment: @Ghazgkull none of the answers answer the question, nor solve a problem.

Comment: @hazzik All of the answers answer the original question. The OP didn't understand how JSON is converted to objects, which has been explained. The "Edit" changed the question, which certainly doesn't justify downvotes.

Comment: No downvotes from me (OP)

Comment: I didn't intend to change the question, I suppose I was looking more for a solution, as opposed to an explaination as to why it is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your Json SHOULD look like is

```
[{"id":"3", "name":"Andy"}, {"id":"1", "name":"Bruce"}, {"id":"4", "name":"Charlie"}, {"id":"2", "name":"David"}]
```

What you're sending is a series of objects (customers), so your data structure should ideally reflect that. And transferring it as an array you can keep the order, as has already been mentioned.

Comment: This is the solution! Not sure why you've been downvoted. Seems like vandalism, every answer got a downvote!

Comment: Wow, someone just posted a new answer which got downvoted as well. I guess someone's having a bad day...

Comment: This is the solution, I was working with dates, for a graph. Values such as 10, 11, 12 Come before 01, 02 , 03. I had to change logic in both backend and frontend man.

Comment: This is not a solution to the original problem, but a convenient workaround

Answer (score 1):

> is there anyway to do this, keeping ALL the data, and maintaining the
>   order

Try utilizing `$.map()` , `Array.prototype.sort()` to return array of values , properties of returned object

```js
var json = {
  "3": "Andy",
  "1": "Bruce",
  "4": "Charlie",
  "2": "David"
};
var res = $.map(json, function(val, key) {
  // keep all data, maintain order
  // return array having value as string with comma ","
  // as separator between `val` from object `key` from object
  // `val`: `Andy` , `key`: `3`
  return [ val + ", " + key ]
}).sort();
console.log(res);
document.body.textContent = res;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Someone downvoted all our answers (looks like I just got an upvote from someone, so back to 0). Either some random troll or the OP?

Comment: @guest271314 how's your answer maintains the order of what server send?

Comment: @hazzik _" how's your answer maintains the order of what server send?"_ See `console` , `document` at stacksnippets . `res` returns array , sorted by value of object property returned , both `val` and `key` returned within resulting array - in same order as original object

Comment: This technially works in this situation, as the data is sorted into alphabetical order. But what if the data is in some other order, that cannot be deduced from the un-ordered data?

Comment: @guest271314 no it does not. It returns in alphabetical order, not in the original order. Try this: {"2":"David", "4":"Charlie", "1":"Bruce", "3":"Andy"}

Comment: @hazzik Yes, properties of original object appear to be in alphabetical order ? _"Try this: {"2":"David", "4":"Charlie", "1":"Bruce", "3":"Andy"}"_ Yes, same result returned ?

Comment: @guest271314 OP just said that while in the example it looks like objects in the alphabetical order, but in real life it can be any other pre-defined.

Comment: @hazzik _"OP just said that while in the example it looks like this, but in real life it can be opposite."_ Should not alter results returned by `$.map()` ,  `.sort()`

Comment: @guest271314 so, the results will be the same, but they will be different to the original order.

Comment: @hazzik _" so, the results will be the same, but they will be different to the original order."_ Expected result appear to be properties of object returned in alphabetical order . If this is not applicable , or expected result , Jan solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31868232/ would probably be more suitable than above solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85364/discussion-between-hazzik-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the order, you must submit a list in the response JSON.

But your data is wrong in this case,

```
response = [{"3":"Andy"},{"1":"Bruce"},{"4":"Charlie"},{"2":"David"}]
```

And then:

```
 $.each(response ,function(index,v){
      console.log(v)
      // or
      //console.log(data[index])

      //And to get the number and name, you must do some trick 

      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(v)) {
          console.log(number,value);
      }
 })
```

> Best solution

You should use a key for the number, What is this number? a `id`, a `rank`?

```
    response = [{"id":3,"name":"Andy"},{"id":1,"name":"Bruce"},{"id":4,"name":"Charlie"},{"id":2,"name":"David"}]
```

And then:

```
 $.each(response ,function(index,value){
      console.log('Id:',value.id,'Name:',value.name);
 });
```

Comment: But i've lost half my data with this solution.

Comment: Oops, it missed me. The correct method is the answering JAN, would by " data[i].id" or "data[i].name"

Comment: This answer misunderstands the question.

Answer (score 0):

When the string that comes over the wire is converted to a Javascript object (the object representing the JSON data), what you end up with is an object like any other with properties and values. There is no ordering of properties in an object.

The object created from the JSON:

```
{"3":"Andy", "1":"Bruce", "4":"Charlie", "2":"David"}
```

is identical to an object created with this Javascript:

```
obj = {}; // <-- Not an array!
obj[1] = 'Andy';
obj[2] = 'Bruce';
obj[3] = 'Charlie';
obj[4] = 'David';
```

If you want to output the object in order of the property **values**, you'll need to first load the values into an array and then sort the array alphabetically.

Something like:

```
var sorted = [];
for (var prop in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        sorted(json[prop]);
    }
}
sorted.sort();
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: The "Edit" to the original question fundamentally changes the request. Still, you should be able to easily solve your problem with the understanding that your original JSON gives you an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a feature?

Yes kind of, the order of properties of object can be up to an implementation. Some browsers do maintain the order, some not. This is what [ES5 Specification says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4):

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

So, as soon as you get an JavaScript object from JSON literal the order of the properties can be lost.

> And how do I stop this from happening?
>
> Is there any way to do this, keeping ALL the data, and maintaining the order in which is received?

The only real way to solve the issue is to specify the order of objects explicitly.